# Как найти и установить модуль pycurl в Python?

Tags: python, windows-7

Особенно важен вопрос, как установить. Ошибка вылезает и на Python27 и на Python34.
Дело происходит в Windows 7 (win64).

```
C:\Python34>wfuzz.py --help  
Traceback (most recent call last):   
 File "C:\Python34\wfuzz.py", line 6, in   
  from reqresp import *   
 File "C:\Python34\reqresp.py", line 7, in   
  import pycurl   
ImportError: No module named pycurl
```

Answer (score 2):

Берите нужный инсталлятор отсюда:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycurl

Все должно установиться без проблем, в том числе библиотека libcurl.dll.

Устанавливать через pip install в данном случае не советую, иначе без танцев с бубном не обойтись. Тут вам не линукс.