# Ошибка при установке pycurl

Tags: python, windows-7, lib

```
C:\Python27>pip install pycurl
Downloading/unpacking pycurl
 Running setup.py (path:c:\users\asus\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_asus\pycurl\setup.py) egg_info for package pycurl
  Please specify --curl-dir=/path/to/built/libcurl
  Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
  Please specify --curl-dir=/path/to/built/libcurl

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 10 in c:\users\asus\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_asus\pycurl
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\asus\pip\pip.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обновил ответ в вопросе [Как найти и установить модуль pycurl в Python?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/381479/windows7-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C-pycurl-%D0%B2-python?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=381482#381482). Этот вопрос закрываю, т.к. это продолжение предыдущего вопроса.